# Facebook Login not working on phone Angular Satellizer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, mobile, satellizer

**Problem**

I'm working on angular and have implemented facebook login through Satellizer. It works well on desktop, but when accessed on mobile, it sometimes work, and sometimes don't. The login pop-up is never closed when it is not working, and it opens the home page in login pop-up, while the main screen which requested login is still waiting for the pop-up to close. Any suggestion what might be wrong here?

**Sample Code**

This is how I'm authenticating from facebook

```
   var commonConfig = {
    popupOptions: {
     location: 'no',
     toolbar: 'yes',
     width: window.screen.width,
     height: window.screen.height
   }
};

var permissions = ["public_profile","email"];
$authProvider.facebook(angular.extend({}, commonConfig, {
  clientId: FacebookAppId,
  url: ApiUrl+'api/v1/facebook/auth',
  scope:permissions,
  scopeDelimiter:','
}));
```

This code is called when "connect using facebook" is pressed

```
    $scope.loginSocial = function () {
    $scope.disableSubmitBtn = true;
    $scope.showSpinner = true;

    $auth.authenticate('facebook')
      .then(function (result) {
        result = angular.fromJson(result.data.code)
        return AuthServerProvider.loginFb(result.facebookCode);
      },function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'facebook-error';
        $scope.disableSubmitBtn = false;
        $scope.showSpinner = false;
      })
      .then(function(){
        $scope.disableSubmitBtn = true;
        $scope.showSpinner = true;
      })
```

This code works perfectly on desktop web browsers, but when accessed through phone browsers "$auth.authenticate('facebook')" fails most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing similar problem with implementing Satellizer. It turned out that the problem was with handling the redirectUri within angular ui.router. 
if you go back to the library documentation you will notice this qoute:

> To avoid potential 404 errors, create server routes for each redirectUri > URL that return 200 OK. Or alternatively, you may render a custom template with a loading spinner. For the moment, a popup will not stay long > enough to see that custom template, due to 20ms interval polling, but in > the future I may add support for overriding this polling interval value.

In the above code you have mentioned, you didn't assign the redirectUri, so it will be defaulted to '/'. If you already have this route handled in a different way it might sometimes get caught by angular routes and being redirected before Satellizer can fetch it. In order to solve this just assign a redirectUri and handle it through angular routes.

For further details please [read this post](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/1021#issue-191778415).